# DB2: No authorized routine named "EBCDIC_CHR" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found

Tags: db2

When I try to create a defined function to convert hex to string in DB2, I encountered the following problem:

```
SQL ERROR[42884]: No authorized routine named "EBCDIC_CHR" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found..SQLCODE=-440,SQLSTATE=42884,DRIVER=4.19.66
```

The details of code is as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION My_HEX2EBCDIC (I_STRING VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
 
BEGIN
DECLARE v_hex1 char(1);
DECLARE v_hex2 char(1);
DECLARE v_int INTEGER;
DECLARE v_start INTEGER;
DECLARE v_string varchar(50);

SET v_start = 1;
SET v_string = '';

WHILE v_start < length(I_string) DO
  SET v_hex1 = substr(i_string,v_start,1);
  SET v_hex2 = substr(i_string,v_start+1,1);
  SET v_int = (locate(v_hex1,'0123456789ABCDEF') - 1 ) * 16 + locate(v_hex2,'0123456789ABCDEF') - 1 ;
  set v_string = v_string || EBCDIC_CHR(v_int);  // error
  SET v_Start = v_Start + 2;
END WHILE;
return v_String;
END
```

I don't know why, and how can I solve it!
Please help me,Thanks!

Comment: What's your db2 platform and version?

Comment: linux db2 v10.5.0.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function as DB2 for Z/OS [EBCDIC_CHR](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_ebcdicchr.html) among Db2 for LUW [scalar functions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/c0000767.html).
DB2 for Z/OS and DB2 for LUW are different products with slightly different sets of built-in functions.

The easiest way to resolve achieve your goal is to create a generic java UDF.

```
public class Convert 
{
  public static byte[] char2byte(String str, String enc) throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException 
  {
    return str.getBytes(enc);
  }

  public static String byte2char(byte[] b, String enc) throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException 
  {
    return new String(b, enc);
  }
}
```

Compile the `Convert.java` file with the following contents and place the  `Convert.class` file to the `~db2instance/sqllib/function` directory, make it readable for the `~db2instance/sqllib/adm/.fenced` file owner (db2 fenced user).

Create a couple of java UDF using this class:

```
create function byte2char(bytes varchar(32672) for bit data, enc varchar(16))
RETURNS varchar(32672)
LANGUAGE JAVA
EXTERNAL NAME 'Convert.byte2char'
DETERMINISTIC
FENCED THREADSAFE
NO SQL
NOT NULL CALL
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
ALLOW PARALLEL
PARAMETER STYLE JAVA;

create function char2byte(str varchar(32672), enc varchar(16))
RETURNS varchar(32672) for bit data
LANGUAGE JAVA
EXTERNAL NAME 'Convert.char2byte'
DETERMINISTIC
FENCED THREADSAFE
NO SQL
NOT NULL CALL
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
ALLOW PARALLEL
PARAMETER STYLE JAVA;
```

Seems, that the hex string representation you provided is for one of the 1381, 1383 or 1386 codepages?
If yes, then try this:

```
VALUES BYTE2CHAR(HEXTORAW('D6A7B8B6503031'), 'IBM-1381')
```

Comment: So what can I do instead ?

Comment: This depends on what you want to do. Please, provide some source hex string sample, and the result you want to get.

Comment: Hex str  is as follows: "D6A7B86503031", I want to convert it to chinese as follows : "支付P01".

Comment: Odd number of hex digits? It can't be a correct hex string representation. What's the source codepage, where the hex representation of `"支付P01` is as you provided?

Comment: Introducing Java method is a good idea, and I was wondering if I could achieve similar using SQL alone. If so, even better.

Comment: I'm afraid, that it's not so easy to manually enter some codepage translation table like IBM-1381 to UTF-8 (or whatever your Db2 database codepage you use) manually in your SQL UDF. It may be large enough. But the JAVA UDF approach is much more generic: you may convert a string in your database codepage to its byte / hex representation in whatever supported codepage and back with such a couple of tiny functions.

Comment: Okay.Thank you very much!